# C# == is different in value types and reference types?

Tags: c#

In Java there are "==" and "equals" operator for reference types and "==" for value types. for reference type, "==" means both objects point to the same location and "equals" means their values are the same. does C# has similar operators for value type and reference types?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, == can be overloaded for reference types. For example:

```
string a = new string('x', 10);
string b = new string('x', 10);
Console.WriteLine(a == b); // True
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)); // False
```

Unless it's overloaded, == means "reference equality" aka "object identity" for reference types. (As Marc says, you may override `Equals` without overloading ==.)

For value types, you have to overload == otherwise the C# compiler won't let you use it for comparisons. .NET itself will provide an implementation of `Equals` which usually does the right thing, but sometimes slowly - in most cases, if you write your own custom value type you'll want to implement `IEquatable<T>` and override `Equals` as well - and quite possibly overload various operators.

Answer (score 8):

C# allows the `==` operator to be overloaded (and the `Equals` method to be overridden - although `==` and `Equals` don't *have* to mean the same thing).

If you want to mean "the same instance", then `object.ReferenceEquals` (for reference-types) is the best option. Value types default to internal equality.

Answer (score 4):

Straight out of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx):

> For predefined value types, the
>   equality operator (==) returns true if
>   the values of its operands are equal,
>   false otherwise. For reference types
>   other than string, == returns true if
>   its two operands refer to the same
>   object. For the string type, ==
>   compares the values of the strings.

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) should be able to give you a perfect answer though :P

Comment: Yes he beat me by 46 seconds! I knew as I was writing my response that Jon would provide a very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

When should I use == and when should I use Equals?

http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/102224.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely the way it works with .NET as well. The [C# FAQ blog explains equals better](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/102224.aspx):

> The Equals method is just a virtual
>   one defined in System.Object, and
>   overridden by whichever classes choose
>   to do so. The == operator is an
>   operator which can be overloaded by
>   classes, but which usually has
>   identity behaviour.
>
> For reference types where == has not
>   been overloaded, it compares whether
>   two references refer to the same
>   object - which is exactly what the
>   implementation of Equals does in
>   System.Object.